# Is there a database for german words with their pronunciation?

Tags: standard-german

I found many databases with most of the german words, but non of them contained the pronunciation of the words. (In Phonetic spelling)
Something like:

Hund - Húnd
OLivenbaum - oˈliːvn̩ba͜um

would be great.

Wiktionary is also not suffient, as it can not be easily parsed by a computer.
Best case would be if the dataset would be free, but it does not have to be.

Comment: You can even download wiktionary in bulk and parse it easily: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/

Comment: Welcome to German SE!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Wiktionary is also not suffient, as it can not be easily parsed by a computer.

Umm, I beg to differ. It's a one-liner.

```
$ curl 2>/dev/null -o- https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hund|grep -m1 'IPA'|sed 's/<\/span>\]<\/dd>//;s/.*>//'
hʊnt

$ curl 2>/dev/null -o- https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Olivenbaum|grep -m1 'IPA'|sed 's/<\/span>\]<\/dd>//;s/.*>//'
oˈliːvn̩ˌbaʊ̯m
```

If you don't know how to do it yourself from that example, give me your word list and I let my computer do it for you.

Comment: Good answer, but wrong SE :D

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
My current word list has approximately 1.2 Million entries. Is there a possibility of getting Ip-banned from wiktionary if i generate too many requests?

Comment: But seeing that the required information can be extracted by just one line of code, makes me think it is maybe better just to download the wiktonary dump, to avoid sending to many requests.

Comment: The dump is in the Mediawiki format, it's even easier to parse.

Comment: @Janka Die Frage wurde [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/72431/gibt-es-eine-liste-aller-deutschen-w%c3%b6rter-mit-den-dazugeh%c3%b6rigen-silbenteilung-un) noch einmal auf Deutsch gestellt, falls Du deine Antwort übersetzen möchtest.

Answer (score 4):

#### Yes, there is:

The [**Deutsche Aussprachedatenbank**](https://dad.sprechwiss.uni-halle.de/dokuwiki/doku.php) ('German pronounciation database', short *DAD*) is a free scientific online database by the University of Halle-Wittenberg with over 130.000 entries based on the [*Deutsches Aussprachewörterbuch*](https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110215564).

It contains your examples:

- [Hund [hʊnt]](https://dad.sprechwiss.uni-halle.de/dokuwiki/doku.php/de/H/Hund)
- [Olivenbaum [olˈiːvn̩baɔ̯m]](https://dad.sprechwiss.uni-halle.de/dokuwiki/doku.php/de/O/Olivenbaum)

Comment: `$ curl 2>/dev/null -o- https://dad.sprechwiss.uni-halle.de/dokuwiki/doku.php/de/O/Olivenbaum|grep -m1 "de.ipa"|sed 's/\]<\/td>//;s/.*>\[//'` if anyone wants to harvest that.