# Gibt es eine Liste aller deutschen Wörter mit den dazugehörigen Silbenteilung und Lautschriften?

Tags: resource, dictionary

So etwas in der Art von:
Hund : Húnd
O-li-ven-baum : oˈliːvn̩ba͜um

Die Liste sollte bestenfalls gut von einem Computerprogramm verarbeitbar sein und nicht so etwas wie ein Datendump vom deutschen Wiktionary.

Alle Listen, die ich bis jetzt gefunden habe waren leider ohne Lautschrift oder Silbenaufteilung.

Comment: Hallo LenzAbi! Herzlich Willkommen auf german.SE! Was meinst du mit "nicht so etwas"? Der Dump vom Wiktionary enthält die gefragten Infos und ist von einem Computerprogramm verarbeitbar. Wenn du das genauer eingrenzt, hilfst du uns, dir zu helfen und erhöhst die Chance, eine Antwort zu bekommen, die dem besser entsprichst, was du suchst.

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/72429/is-there-a-database-for-german-words-with-their-pronunciation - die gleiche Frage vom gleichen Fragesteller in Englisch, gestellt vor 24h, mit einer guten Antwort, vielleicht sogar mit der best möglichen Antwort

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a database for german words with their pronunciation?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/72429/is-there-a-database-for-german-words-with-their-pronunciation)

Comment: Technically not a duplicate, since it's a different language, but I fail to see the reason to ask the same question twice.

Comment: @infinitezero i think we can make an exception.

Comment: Danke für die schnellen Antworten! Ich habe die Frage extra auf 2 Sprachen gestellt, um ggf. auch von Leuten Antworten zu bekommen, die englisch, aber kein deutsch sprechen. Denn die meisten der ähnlichen Threads, die ich gefunden habe waren auch auf englisch. Falls das nicht erlaubt ist, werde ich das in Zukunft unterlassen. Trotzdem danke für die Antworten!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das Wiktionary ist ziemlich gut von einem Computerprogramm verarbeitbar. Man sollte bloß das richtige Werkzeug verwenden:

```
$ curl 2>/dev/null -o- https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hund|grep -m1 'IPA'|sed 's/<\/span>\]<\/dd>//;s/.*>//'
hʊnt

$ curl 2>/dev/null -o- https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Olivenbaum|grep -m1 'IPA'|sed 's/<\/span>\]<\/dd>//;s/.*>//'
oˈliːvn̩ˌbaʊ̯m
```

Die Silben kannst du ähnlich herausfinden.

```
$ curl 2>/dev/null -o- https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Olivenbaum|grep -m1 -A1 "Worttrennung:"|tail -n1|sed 's/^<dl><dd>//;s/,.*//'
Oli·ven·baum
```

Answer (score 2):

Ja, die [**Deutsche Aussprachedatenbank**](https://dad.sprechwiss.uni-halle.de/dokuwiki/doku.php) (DAD) der Uni Halle basiert auf dem  [*Deutschen Aussprachewörterbuch*](https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110215564) und enthält für über 130.000 Wörter die [IPA](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationales_Phonetisches_Alphabet)- und [SAMPA](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAMPA)-Lautschrift sowie weitere Angaben wie die Silbenzahl. Aus der SAMPA-Lautschrift ergibt sich auch die Silbenaufteilung.

Deine Beispiele:

- [Hund [hʊnt]](https://dad.sprechwiss.uni-halle.de/dokuwiki/doku.php/de/H/Hund)
- [Olivenbaum [olˈiːvn̩baɔ̯m] (SAMPA: [o.l"i:.vn=.baO^m])](https://dad.sprechwiss.uni-halle.de/dokuwiki/doku.php/de/O/Olivenbaum)